# Jsp page is running even after tab close

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I know, writing scriptlet code in jsp is bad habit but here I did this just for understaing Jsp/Servlet concepts.

So tell me, Why this page is running even after closing tab before reaching false condition? How to stop it on closing tab?

**test.jsp :**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    int i=0;
    while(i<100)
    {
        i++;
        System.out.println("Test is called...["+i+"]");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're just learning, skip raw servlets and JSPs entirely. Use something like Spring MVC with Thymeleaf, which offers a dramatically simpler setup, cleaner controller code, and friendlier page templating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this code is running on the server, not in the browser, and the server doesn't generally have a way to tell that you closed a page. If the TCP connection drops, the script will probably eventually throw an exception.